# Error java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB

Tags: java, android

I got an eror stack size. I hv no idea about this error. Because when I compile this project in another android studio. It works fine. But now in not working anymore and i got this error. This error will show when i choose an option in my radio group. I hv 2 radio group and edittext, when I choose the data from one of the radio group the other option in another radio group and edittext will be clear. But i got an error in the clear part in   setOnCheckedChangeListener function. Please help me. Thank you
ChargeFragment.java

```
public class ChargeFragment extends Fragment {
CustomerPreference customerPreference;
DiscountPeferences discountPeferences;
CartPreference cartPreference;
SessionManagement sessionManagement;
DatabaseHandler db;
List<CartModel> cart;
List<Discount> dp;

Fragment fragment = null;

Button Charge,Cancel;
RadioButton rb1,rb2,rbEdc,rbOther,rbPay1,rbPay2,rbPay3;
RadioGroup rg,rOther,rgPay;
TextView tvTotal;
EditText edCard,edCash;
public ChargeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_charge, container, false);

    sessionManagement = new SessionManagement(getActivity());
    db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
    cartPreference = new CartPreference();
    customerPreference = new CustomerPreference(getActivity());
    discountPeferences = new DiscountPeferences();
    cart = cartPreference.getFavorites(getActivity());
    dp = discountPeferences.getFavorites(getActivity());

    Bundle bun=this.getArguments();
    final int total=bun.getInt("total");

    tvTotal = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.tvTotal);
    rg = (RadioGroup) rootview.findViewById(R.id.radioChoose);
    rb1 = (RadioButton) rootview.findViewById(R.id.rd1);
    rb2 = (RadioButton) rootview.findViewById(R.id.rd2);
    rOther = (RadioGroup) rootview.findViewById(R.id.radioOther);
    rgPay = (RadioGroup) rootview.findViewById(R.id.rgPay);
    rbEdc = (RadioButton) rootview.findViewById(R.id.rdEdc);
    rbOther = (RadioButton) rootview.findViewById(R.id.rdOthr);
    rbPay1 = (RadioButton) rootview.findViewById(R.id.rdPay1);
    rbPay2 = (RadioButton) rootview.findViewById(R.id.rdPay2);
    rbPay3 = (RadioButton) rootview.findViewById(R.id.rdPay3);
    Charge = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.buttonCharge);
    Cancel = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.buttonCancel);
    edCard = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.edCard);
    edCash = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.edCash);


    int x = Math.round((total + 900)/1000 * 1000);
    int y = Math.round((total + 9000)/10000 * 10000);
    rbPay1.setText(""+total);
    rbPay2.setText(""+x);
    rbPay3.setText(""+y);

    final DecimalFormat kursIndonesia = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    DecimalFormatSymbols formatRp = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    formatRp.setCurrencySymbol("Rp. ");
    formatRp.setMonetaryDecimalSeparator(',');
    formatRp.setGroupingSeparator('.');
    kursIndonesia.setDecimalFormatSymbols(formatRp);

    tvTotal.setText(""+kursIndonesia.format(total));

    edCard.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            rOther.clearCheck();
            rbEdc.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            rbOther.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });

    edCash.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            rg.clearCheck();
            rb1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            rb2.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            rOther.clearCheck();
            rbEdc.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            rbOther.setTextColor(Color.RED);

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });

    rgPay.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            if(rbPay1.isChecked())
                edCash.setText(rbPay1.getText().toString());
            if(rbPay2.isChecked())
                edCash.setText(rbPay2.getText().toString());
            if(rbPay3.isChecked())
                edCash.setText(rbPay3.getText().toString());
        }
    });

    rOther.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {

            rgPay.clearCheck();
            //edCash.setText("");
            if (rbEdc.isChecked()) {
                rbEdc.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                rbOther.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            }
            if (rbOther.isChecked()){
                rbEdc.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                rbOther.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            }
        }
    });

    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {

           // rOther.clearCheck();
            rbEdc.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            rbOther.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            edCash.setText("");
            if (rb1.isChecked()) {
                rb1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                rb2.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            }
            if (rb2.isChecked()){
                rb1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                rb2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            }
        }
    });

    Cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    Charge.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            int last=1;

            String method = "", pay = "";
            if (!edCash.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                method = "Cash";
                pay = edCash.getText().toString();
            } else if (!edCard.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                method = "Debit/Credit";
                pay = "" + total;
            } else if (edCard.getText().toString().equals("") && edCash.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                if (rbEdc.isChecked()) {
                    method = "EDC";
                } else if (rbOther.isChecked()) {
                    method = "Other";
                }
                pay = "" + total;
            }
            String cardNo = "";
            if (edCard.getText().equals(""))
                cardNo = "";
            else {
                cardNo = edCard.getText().toString();
            }

            if(method.equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Choose Payment Method Please !",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {

                String discID = "";
                String discID2 = "";
                int listDiscCount = db.getDiscCount();
                if (dp != null) {
                    discID = db.getMaxIdListDiscount();
                    if (dp.size() > 0) {
                        if (listDiscCount > 0) {
                            discID2 = generateListDiscId(Integer.parseInt(discID.substring(discID.length() - 3)) + 1);
                        } else {
                            discID2 = generateListDiscId(1);
                        }
                        for (Discount d : dp) {
                            String pkDisc;
                            if (listDiscCount == 0)
                                pkDisc = generateIdListDiscPk(1);
                            else {
                                String lastPkDisc = db.getMaxPkIdListDiscount();
                                pkDisc = generateIdListDiscPk(Integer.parseInt(lastPkDisc.substring(lastPkDisc.length() - 3)) + 1);
                            }
                            list_disc_nota ld = new list_disc_nota(pkDisc, discID2, d.getId());
                            db.addListDiscNota(ld);
                        }
                    }
                }

                insertItemNota();


                int total1 = 0;
                for (CartModel cm : cart) {
                    total1 = total1 + Integer.parseInt(cm.getHarga());
                }
                if (dp != null) {
                    if (dp.size() > 0) {
                        InsertNota(method, discID2, cardNo, "" + total1, "" + total);
                    } else
                        InsertNota(method, "0", cardNo, "" + total1, "" + total);
                } else {
                    InsertNota(method, "0", cardNo, "" + total1, "" + total);
                }


                int change = Integer.parseInt(pay) - total;
                String nota = db.getLastNotaID();
                if(method.equals("Debit/Credit"))
                {
                    method="Card";
                }
                showPrint(nota, total, Integer.parseInt(pay), change,method);
            }
        }
    });
    return rootview;
}
```

Error Stack

```
                  Process: com.project.pos.posandroid, PID: 2773
                  java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:5377)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:5424)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:5424)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:5424)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:5424)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:5424)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:5424)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:5424)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:5424)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:5424)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:5424)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:5424)
                      at android.view.View.getGlobalVisibleRect(View.java:12274)
                      at android.view.View.isVisibleToUser(View.java:6544)
                      at android.view.View.isVisibleToUser(View.java:6502)
                      at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(View.java:6421)
                      at android.widget.TextView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(TextView.java:8978)
                      at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:6105)
                      at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(View.java:6064)
                      at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:6049)
                      at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord.setSource(AccessibilityRecord.java:145)
                      at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord.setSource(AccessibilityRecord.java:119)
                      at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEventInternal(View.java:6001)
                      at android.widget.TextView.onInitializeAccessibilityEventInternal(TextView.java:8963)
                      at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(View.java:5989)
                      at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUncheckedInternal(View.java:5854)
                      at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:5839)
                      at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventInternal(View.java:5816)
                      at android.widget.TextView.sendAccessibilityEventInternal(TextView.java:9163)
                      at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEvent(View.java:5783)
                      at android.widget.TextView.onSelectionChanged(TextView.java:7943)
                      at android.widget.TextView.spanChange(TextView.java:8160)
                      at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanAdded(TextView.java:10252)
                      at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1053)
                      at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:759)
                      at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:658)
                      at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:78)
                      at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:87)
                      at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.initialize(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:325)
                      at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4354)
                      at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4223)
                      at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:84)
                      at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4198)
                      at com.project.pos.posandroid.Fragment.ChargeFragment$5.onCheckedChanged(ChargeFragment.java:209)
                      at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:173)
                      at android.widget.RadioGroup.check(RadioGroup.java:167)
                      at android.widget.RadioGroup.clearCheck(RadioGroup.java:209)
                      at com.project.pos.posandroid.Fragment.ChargeFragment$2.onTextChanged(ChargeFragment.java:155)
                      at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8048)
                      at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4369)
                      at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4223)
                      at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:84)
                      at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4198)
                      at com.project.pos.posandroid.Fragment.ChargeFragment$5.onCheckedChanged(ChargeFragment.java:209)
                      at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:173)
                      at android.widget.RadioGroup.check(RadioGroup.java:167)
                    at android.widget.RadioGroup.clearChec
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5237(654KB) AllocSpace objects, 5(45MB) LOS objects, 22% free, 55MB/71MB, paused 689us total 130.901ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 71632(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 4(27MB) LOS objects, 23% free, 52MB/68MB, paused 906us total 126.400ms
D/Error: ERR: exClass=java.lang.StackOverflowError
D/Error: ERR: exMsg=stack size 8MB
D/Error: ERR: file=ViewGroup.java
D/Error: ERR: class=android.view.ViewGroup
D/Error: ERR: method=getChildVisibleRect line=5377
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 65308(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 85MB/85MB, paused 8.070ms total 84.901ms
D/Error: ERR: stack=java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
             at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:5377)
             at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:5424)
             at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:5424)
             at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:5424)
             at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:5424)
             at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:5424)
             at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:5424)
             at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:5424)
             at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:5424)
             at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:5424)
             at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:5424)
             at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:5424)
             at android.view.View.getGlobalVisibleRect(View.java:12274)
             at android.view.View.isVisibleToUser(View.java:6544)
             at android.view.View.isVisibleToUser(View.java:6502)
             at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(View.java:6421)
             at android.widget.TextView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(TextView.java:8978)
             at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:6105)
             at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(View.java:6064)
             at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:6049)
             at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord.setSource(AccessibilityRecord.java:145)
             at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord.setSource(AccessibilityRecord.java:119)
             at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEventInternal(View.java:6001)
             at android.widget.TextView.onInitializeAccessibilityEventInternal(TextView.java:8963)
             at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(View.java:5989)
             at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUncheckedInternal(View.java:5854)
             at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:5839)
             at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventInternal(View.java:5816)
             at android.widget.TextView.sendAccessibilityEventInternal(TextView.java:9163)
             at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEvent(View.java:5783)
             at android.widget.TextView.onSelectionChanged(TextView.java:7943)
             at android.widget.TextView.spanChange(TextView.java:8160)
             at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanAdded(TextView.java:10252)
             at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1053)
             at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:759)
             at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:658)
             at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:78)
             at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:87)
             at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.initialize(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:325)
             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4354)
             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4223)
             at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:84)
             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4198)
             at com.project.pos.posandroid.Fragment.ChargeFragment$5.onCheckedChanged(ChargeFragment.java:209)
             at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:173)
             at android.widget.RadioGroup.check(RadioGroup.java:167)
             at android.widget.RadioGroup.clearCheck(RadioGroup.java:209)
             at com.project.pos.posandroid.Fragment.ChargeFragment$2.onTextChanged(ChargeFragment.java:155)
             at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8048)
             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4369)
             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4223)
             at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:84)
             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4198)
             at com.project.pos.posandroid.Fragment.ChargeFragment$5.onCheckedChanged(ChargeFragment.java:209)
             at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:173)
             at android.widget.RadioGroup.check(RadioGroup.java:167)
             at android.widget.RadioGroup.clearCheck(RadioGroup.java:209)
            at com.project.pos.posandroid.Fragment.Char
D/Error: ERR: TOTAL BYTES WRITTEN: 10556588
E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 10556680)
E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
                  android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 10556680 bytes
                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
                      at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4463)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:90)
                      at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                      at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2773 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Can we please have only relevant code here? What about the view - is it possible that your view contains itself?

Comment: i made it in fragment so the view is in the oncreateview. thats the only place where i put the code - @M.Prokhorov

Comment: According to exception and an answer to your question, the actual code sample should've been ten to fifteen lines long, not this. Please refer to [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow/help/mcve) in future questions.

Answer (score 0):

The code in effect is working like a while loop without a break condition.
In edCash's checked change listener you are calling rg.clearCheck() which inturn will invoke oncheckchange lsitener of rg. In rg's on checked change listener you are setting setting text for edCach which in turn will call edCash's on text change listner. For programmatical changes pass toggle between a null& your listner for these widgets to avoid a loop

For eg:

```
@Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            rg.setOnCheckedChangeListner(null);
            rg.clearCheck();
            rg.setOnCheckedChangeListner(yourCheckBoxListner);
            rbEdc.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            rbOther.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
And for rg
  @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {

        rbEdc.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        rbOther.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        edCash.setonTextChangeListener(null);
        edCash.setText("");
        edCash.setOnTextChangeListner(youTextChangeListner);

rg.setoncheckChangeListner(yourCheckBoxListner);

WHERE yourCheckBoxListner would be like.-->
    RadioGroup.OnCheckChangeListner yourCheckBoxListner = new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) { 
       //yourlogic  like below. 
     rbEdc.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                rbOther.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                edCash.setonTextChangeListener(null);
                edCash.setText("");
                edCash.setOnTextChangeListner(youTextChangeListner);
    }
```

Do the same for edCash Also.

Comment: do u hv any idea how to fix it?

Comment: but i want it to be clear when i choose another radio group. Hmm is that mean not possible to clear another when i change ediitext or radiogroup?